# Is it possible to restrict public enum values in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, private, encapsulation, public

I am currently writing a software program for a tour, made up of exhibits. The exhibit object, at any given point, is in one of four states, defined by the ExhibitStates enum:

```
private enum ExhibitState { Ready, Active, Complete, Inactive };
```

For developers who will be setting up exhibits, there are only two "starting" states that I want them to be able to choose from:

```
public enum StartingExhibitState { Ready, Inactive };
```

Currently, I have it set up so that upon being initialized, the exhibit will immediately set its state to match its starting state, like so:

```
        switch (startingState) {
            case StartingExhibitState.Ready:
                SetState(ExhibitState.Ready);
                break;
            case StartingExhibitState.Inactive:
                SetState(ExhibitState.Inactive);
                break;
        }
```

I found myself wondering today if this was the best practice. Is there a better way to restrict which enum options are public and which are private? Or is it best to simply have the two separate enums?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to restrict the "setting" of the enum value in your class?

Comment: The way your switch statement is set up, you could simply set the state at once, or set cases for the once you don't want to use, break out of them at once, and set the state in the default action. I would also assume there would be logic whether a state can really switch from inactive to complete?

Comment: You could default to `Inactive` and supply a `SetReady` method, obviating the need for passing a starting state at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create second enum - your intents will be very clearly explained through signature of setting method

```
public enum ExhibitState 
{ 
    Inactive = 0,
    Active = 1,
    Ready = 2,
    Complete = 3
};

public enum InitialStates 
{ 
    Inactive = ExhibitState.Inactive,
    Ready = ExhibitState.Ready
};

public void SetInitial(InitialStates state)
{
    SetState((ExhibitState)state);
}
```

If you go further you can add compiler help for preventing passing wrong values to the method.

```
public sealed class InitialState
{
    public static readonly InitialState Initial = new InitialState(ExhibitState.Initial);

    public static readonly InitialState Ready = new InitialState(ExhibitState.Ready);

    public ExhibitState State { get; }            

    private InitialState(ExhibitState state)
    {
        State = state;
    }
}
```

Constructor made `private` to prevent instantiating class from else where.
Class marked as `sealed` to prevent deriving and changing it behaviour.

Then your method will look like

```
public void SetInitial(InitialState start)
{
    SetState(start.State);
}  

// use it
SetInitial(InitialState.Initial);
SetInitial(InitialState.Ready);
```

Nothing else cannot be passed, until you change code of `InitialState` class.

Comment: Your enum values do not match. You should declare `public enum InitialStates { Ready, Inactive = 3 };`, otherwise `InitialStates.Inactive` will be mapped to `ExhibitState.Active`.

Comment: You can be explicit: `public enum InitialStates { Ready = ExhibitState.Ready, Inactive = ExhibitState.Inactive };`

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. I was wondering if it was the best approach or if there was something simpler. I suppose this is the way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an enum (or two of them), you could use a class-based approach:

```
public abstract class ExhibitState 
{
    public static ExhibitInitialState Ready { get { return new ExhibitReadyState(); } }
    public static ExhibitInitialState Inactive { get { return new ExhibitInactiveState(); } }
    public static ExhibitState Complete { get { return new ExhibitCompleteState(); } }
    public static ExhibitState Active { get { return new ExhibitActiveState(); } }

    private class ExhibitReadyState : ExhibitInitialState {}
    private class ExhibitInactiveState : ExhibitInitialState {}
    private class ExhibitCompleteState : ExhibitState {}
    private class ExhibitActiveState : ExhibitState {}
}

public abstract class ExhibitInitialState : ExhibitState {}
```

The above sample shows a simple approach. Usually, you'd not create a new instance of a state in the `get` methods, but have static instances so that comparing is easier.

Similar to an enum, you could still type `ExhibitState.Ready` or the other states. In addition, the base class `ExhibitInitialState` allows you to limit the states that can be set initially:

```
public void SetInitial(ExhibitInitialState initState) { ... }
```

In comparison to the approach that @Fabio proposed, you'd have the benefit that you could not mix up the values. Furthermore and especially relevant for states: is very common that the behavior should also change for a specific state. With this class-based approach, you could implement this behavior in the specific `ExhibitState` implementations and by that avoid lots of `switch` statements that are likely to exist in an enum-based approach.

Comment: If you go this route, consider not creating a new instance of the state sub-classes every time.  You can use the new language features of C# 6 (read-only auto-properties) to get the same instance each time from this class `public static ExhibitInitialState Ready { get ;} = new ExhibitReadyState();`.  This will make comparing states through equality checking easier, without having to mess with equatability and hashes.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yes, you're right. I just wanted to keep the sample short & simple.